# Frequency of Riemann Zeta function oscillations around 1

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

When one looks at the Riemann Zeta function along the critical line, one clearly sees some irregular oscillations (see [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-H8Do9JSn4)). As one moves the vertical line to the right, the oscillations become more regular and clearly centered around one (1+0i). By the time you reach vertical line at x=10, they are fairly regular, even though their amplitude is quite small.

[image: zeta oscillation]]

Is there a way to calculate what is the period (or frequency) of these oscillations? It seems that the period is a tad over 9 (I'd say 9.06 or so), but I do know know where to start with verifying such observation (the oscillations can also be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_YrwZ7L84k), if you watch the green end of the curve).

The above mentioned value of the period can be seen on the right when one looks at the domain coloring map, except one needs to plot Zeta(z)-1, otherwise the small oscillations around 1 will have argument close to 0 (and there will be sea of red on the right).

[image: zeta coloring]

Comment: For $\Re(s)$ large : $\zeta(s)  = 1+2^{-s}+ \mathcal{O}(3^{-\sigma})$ thus the frequency is $\frac{\log 2}{2\pi}$

Comment: The period is hence $\frac{2\pi}{\log 2} \approx 9.0647$. The larger $n$ give suerpositions of even smaller circles over the main contribution coming from $2$.

Comment: For $\Re(s)$ large negative we can do the same using the functional equation involving $\pi^{-s}$ thus we'll have a dominant frequency $\frac{\log 2}{2\pi}+ \frac{\log \pi}{2\pi}$ (frequency on vertical strips)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That explains the Technicolor picture on both ends and improves the quality of my sleep by π/ln(2)  :-)